# Extracting a linkedlist from an array of linkedlist

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I am trying to extract a linkedlist from an array of linkedlist and am stuck. After extracting this linkedlist, I would need to sum the number of fruits in each basket in each linkedlist. For example, Basket 0 returns 174, Basket 1 returns 147, etc.

I've tried using an iterator and listIterator (as well) to extract the number of fruits but I am not getting anywhere. Anyone who can help? Some pointers/hints so I can start coding again.

```
public class ArrayLinkedList {

    final static int NUM_OF_ROWS = 32767;

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        List[] basket = new List [NUM_OF_ROWS];

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ROWS; i++) {
            basket[i] = new LinkedList();
        }

        basket[0].add("1,APPLE,12");
        basket[1].add("2,APPLE,14");
        basket[1].add("3,APPLE,9");
        basket[2].add("4,APPLE,90");
        basket[2].add("5,APPLE,13");

        basket[0].add("1,ORANGE,45");
        basket[0].add("2,ORANGE,19");
        basket[1].add("3,ORANGE,67");
        basket[1].add("4,ORANGE,33");

        basket[0].add("1,BANANA,2");
        basket[0].add("2,BANANA,96");
        basket[1].add("3,BANANA,16");
        basket[1].add("4,BANANA,8");
        basket[2].add("5,BANANA,14");
        basket[2].add("6,BANANA,26");
        basket[3].add("7,BANANA,8");
        basket[3].add("8,BANANA,5");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           System.out.println("Basket " + i + ": " + rows[i].toString());
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a string to store multiple information. This would force you to parse the string each time you want to get a part of the information. I don't know what `"1,APPLE,12"` represents, but you should use an object instead of this string :

```
public class Item {
    private int something;
    private String fruitName;
    private int numberOfFruits;

    public Item(int something, String fruitName, int numberOfFruits) {
        this.something = something;
        this.fruitName = fruitName;
        this.numberOfFruits = numberOfFruits;
    }

    public int getSomething() {
        return this.something;
    }

    public String getFruitName() {
        return this.fruitName;
    }

    public int getNumberOfFruits() {
        return this.numberOfFruits;
    }
}
```

And then, your array of baskets can be built like this :

```
List<Item>[] basket = new List<Basket>[NUM_OF_ROWS];

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_ROWS; i++) {
    basket[i] = new LinkedList<Item>();
}

basket[0].add(new Item(1, "APPLE", 12));
basket[1].add(new Item(2, "APPLE", 14));
// ...
```

Then, you may iterate over one of the baskets and compute the total number of fruits easily :

```
int totalNumber = 0;
for (Item item : basket[0]) {
    totalNumber += item.getNumberOfFruits();
}
```

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, Thanks for your response! I am having a ton of trouble trying to think in terms of OOP. You have made it much easier for me to start thinking!

Comment: Hi JB Nizet, Could you help me on this "List<Item>[] basket = new List<Basket>[NUM_OF_ROWS];" What does the '<Basket>' mean here?

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that this is homework.

What you are doing so far is to create an array of lists adding strings to the lists.

You can get the number of items in a list via the `.size()` method, but you probably want to add the numbers you put into the strings.

One approach would be to:

- define a Fruit class with three attributes
- instantiating Fruit objects to add to the baskets (lists)
- use a for loop to address each basket
- use an iterator on each basket list to count the fruit

success!

Comment: +1 from me - this one and the one after it are the best answers.

Comment: Hi rsp, thanks for your note. You're right on all counts. I should have considered using a Fruit class. I'm new to OOP and am still not good at thinking in terms of OOP.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is going nowhere.

I'd recommend starting with a Basket class and a Fruit enum (no guarantees that this compiles - you work it out):

```
public enum Fruit { APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE; }

public class Basket
{
    private Fruit fruit;
    private int quantity;
    // you add the rest, including equals and hashCode overrides
}
```

Create a `List<Fruit>` and go from there.

Comment: Hi duffymo, Thanks for your response! I was reading Java generics and still have no idea how to use it. Your example is helping a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through `basket` array, then for each entry iterate through the `List`, getting each basket entry (a basket entry is for example 1,APPLE,12. Sum up the number of fruit for each basket entry and you have your total.

Also, you might want to make your list non generic with `String`.

```
//Iterate through the basket array
for (List<String> list : basket) {
  int totalNumberOfFruit = 0;

  //Iterate through the basket entries
  for (String s : list) {
    //s here will have the value for eg "1,APPLE,12"
    //you need to extract the number of fruit, perhaps
    //with s.split(",") and then add the number to
    //totalNumberOfFruit

  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Qwerky, Thanks for your response! I'll think about this!